# Delete counter for some items?

Tags: counters

Now I have the counter which generates number sign and 2 numbers like 1.1 (for the first problem in 1st section):

```
\newcounter{zzadacha}[section]
\newcommand{\zz}{\addtocounter{zzadacha}{1}%
\textbf{\hspace{1 pt} 
\color{blue}\textnumero \hspace{1 pt}\arabic{section}.\arabic{zzadacha}\,} }
```

Then I use it in document

`\zz $45$; \zz $-67$.`.. etc

Everything works alright, 30 probles in my 1st section.
The question is - how to skip in printig, say items number 1, 12 and 29? The other items must have their own preserverd numbers.

Please, any ideas.

Comment: Simply skip your command where you don't like to use and in the next occurrence of it use manually increment it with `\addtocounter{zzadacha}{1}`

Answer (score 4):

Redefine `\zz` to check for an optional argument.  Anything non-blank will inhibit the blue text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\textnumero{No.}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{zzadacha}[section]
\newcommand{\zz}[1][]{\addtocounter{zzadacha}{1}%
\if\relax#1\relax\textbf{\hspace{1 pt} 
\color{blue}\textnumero \hspace{1 pt}\arabic{section}.\arabic{zzadacha}\,} \fi}

\section{First}
\zz text

\section{Next}
\zz[x] text

\section{Third}
\zz text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, Steven, your answer is universal. I'll keep it in mind, thank you!